How many letters in this word? خطيـٔـتهم
Some people claim that chapter 71 (Nuh) contains 950 letters, same as the years for which Prophet Nuh (pbuh) preached his nation according to 29:14
Here are the scanned images, demonstrating how they counted them as 950

part 1
part 2
part 3
part 4
part 5
part 6
part 7

Popularly, people count the number of letters in chapter 71 as 953. I wrote a python script to count number of letters and words in a given ayah after stripping all the vowel marks and stuff and it counts the letters in chapter 71 as 953, below will be the detailed output of my program for chapter 71. In those images they have reduced letters in verse: 7, 23, 25. They changed count of these words:

ءاذانهم - Saying the alif after hamza is just a vowel but then what about the alif after dhaal? remove that as well.
ءالهتكم - Same.
خطيـٔـتهم - Removed the hamza, only counted kha, tau, ya, ta, ha, ma; but when we read this word we read: khatyii-aatihim i.e. the ya is the long vowel here and the hamza is a consonant if I did it right, we can't remove anything, there has to be 7 letters in this word.

Have they done it the right way or there is no 950 magic in chapter 71?
====Verse num: 1====
إنا أرسلنا نوحا إلى قومه أن أنذر قومك من قبل أن يأتيهم عذاب أليم
Letters each word: 3 6 4 3 4 2 4 4 2 3 2 6 4 4
Word count : 14
Char count : 51
====Verse num: 2====
قال يقوم إنى لكم نذير مبين
Letters each word: 3 4 3 3 4 4
Word count : 6
Char count : 21
====Verse num: 3====
أن اعبدوا الله واتقوه وأطيعون
Letters each word: 2 6 4 6 7
Word count : 5
Char count : 25
====Verse num: 4====
يغفر لكم من ذنوبكم ويؤخركم إلى أجل مسمى إن أجل الله إذا جاء لا يؤخر لو كنتم تعلمون
Letters each word: 4 3 2 6 7 3 3 4 2 3 4 3 3 2 4 2 4 6
Word count : 18
Char count : 65
====Verse num: 5====
قال رب إنى دعوت قومى ليلا ونهارا
Letters each word: 3 2 3 4 4 4 6
Word count : 7
Char count : 26
====Verse num: 6====
فلم يزدهم دعاءى إلا فرارا
Letters each word: 3 5 5 3 5
Word count : 5
Char count : 21
====Verse num: 7====
وإنى كلما دعوتهم لتغفر لهم جعلوا أصبعهم فى ءاذانهم واستغشوا ثيابهم وأصروا واستكبروا استكبارا
Letters each word: 4 4 6 5 3 5 6 2 7 8 6 6 9 8
Word count : 14
Char count : 79
====Verse num: 8====
ثم إنى دعوتهم جهارا
Letters each word: 2 3 6 5
Word count : 4
Char count : 16
====Verse num: 9====
ثم إنى أعلنت لهم وأسررت لهم إسرارا
Letters each word: 2 3 5 3 6 3 6
Word count : 7
Char count : 28
====Verse num: 10====
فقلت استغفروا ربكم إنه كان غفارا
Letters each word: 4 8 4 3 3 5
Word count : 6
Char count : 27
====Verse num: 11====
يرسل السماء عليكم مدرارا
Letters each word: 4 6 5 6
Word count : 4
Char count : 21
====Verse num: 12====
ويمددكم بأمول وبنين ويجعل لكم جنت ويجعل لكم أنهرا
Letters each word: 7 5 5 5 3 3 5 3 5
Word count : 9
Char count : 41
====Verse num: 13====
ما لكم لا ترجون لله وقارا
Letters each word: 2 3 2 5 3 5
Word count : 6
Char count : 20
====Verse num: 14====
وقد خلقكم أطوارا
Letters each word: 3 5 6
Word count : 3
Char count : 14
====Verse num: 15====
ألم تروا كيف خلق الله سبع سموت طباقا
Letters each word: 3 4 3 3 4 3 4 5
Word count : 8
Char count : 29
====Verse num: 16====
وجعل القمر فيهن نورا وجعل الشمس سراجا
Letters each word: 4 5 4 4 4 5 5
Word count : 7
Char count : 31
====Verse num: 17====
والله أنبتكم من الأرض نباتا
Letters each word: 5 6 2 5 5
Word count : 5
Char count : 23
====Verse num: 18====
ثم يعيدكم فيها ويخرجكم إخراجا
Letters each word: 2 6 4 7 6
Word count : 5
Char count : 25
====Verse num: 19====
والله جعل لكم الأرض بساطا
Letters each word: 5 3 3 5 5
Word count : 5
Char count : 21
====Verse num: 20====
لتسلكوا منها سبلا فجاجا
Letters each word: 7 4 4 5
Word count : 4
Char count : 20
====Verse num: 21====
قال نوح رب إنهم عصونى واتبعوا من لم يزده ماله وولده إلا خسارا
Letters each word: 3 3 2 4 5 7 2 2 4 4 5 3 5
Word count : 13
Char count : 49
====Verse num: 22====
ومكروا مكرا كبارا
Letters each word: 6 4 5
Word count : 3
Char count : 15
====Verse num: 23====
وقالوا لا تذرن ءالهتكم ولا تذرن ودا ولا سواعا ولا يغوث ويعوق ونسرا
Letters each word: 6 2 4 7 3 4 3 3 5 3 4 5 5
Word count : 13
Char count : 54
====Verse num: 24====
وقد أضلوا كثيرا ولا تزد الظلمين إلا ضللا
Letters each word: 3 5 5 3 3 7 3 4
Word count : 8
Char count : 33
====Verse num: 25====
مما خطئتهم أغرقوا فأدخلوا نارا فلم يجدوا لهم من دون الله أنصارا
Letters each word: 3 7 6 7 4 3 5 3 2 3 4 6
Word count : 12
Char count : 53
====Verse num: 26====
وقال نوح رب لا تذر على الأرض من الكفرين ديارا
Letters each word: 4 3 2 2 3 3 5 2 7 5
Word count : 10
Char count : 36
====Verse num: 27====
إنك إن تذرهم يضلوا عبادك ولا يلدوا إلا فاجرا كفارا
Letters each word: 3 2 5 5 5 3 5 3 5 5
Word count : 10
Char count : 41
====Verse num: 28====
رب اغفر لى ولولدى ولمن دخل بيتى مؤمنا وللمؤمنين والمؤمنت ولا تزد الظلمين إلا تبارا
Letters each word: 2 4 2 6 4 3 4 5 9 8 3 3 7 3 5
Word count : 15
Char count : 68

226, 953


What even do you mean by "the right way"? The prophet was famously illiterate; the Qur'an was transmitted orally. It's unclear where you expect to find any sort of "official" Islamic categorization of letterforms.

@goldPseudo That makes sense. I would say the right way would be the most minimal script in this case, reducing any letter more will compromise meaning. Anyways, can you point me to some resources of numerical studies of Qur'an? i.e. Studies performed on mathematics and numerical structure of Qur'an

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

I'd say that it is rather speculative whether the count is correct or not. It could be that the counter is relying on a specific number of letters, as there are differing opinions in Arabic about whether Hamza and Shaddah etc. are even counted as separate letters. On the other hand, it is possible that he found ways to achieve his desired result, which seems more likely to be the case here, since the counting seems rather inconsistent at first glance. For example he always counted the hamza as such so how can

خطيـٔـتهم

suddenly, be only counted as of 6 letters.
Further more, what is a correct counting here at all? Since the spelling of letters in the qur'an is incorrect according to today's Modern Arabic. And the qur'an was transmitted via different readings. For example, your word of interest should be written:

خطيئاتهم

according to one correct reading (having even 8 letters) or

خَطَايَاهُمْ

according another (7 letters) so how can we count correctly?
What is the basis of the count? Without this information we can't answer your question, and without it the statement of the person claiming that the amount of letters is 950 is vague or a rather magic number.

Very true, the different riwaayah of the quran can change the number very easily
